# How to uninstall Homebrew Cask

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

I installed Homebrew Cask for kicks as described at http://caskroom.io/. It boils down to the following command:

```
$ brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
$ brew tap caskroom/versions
```

Homebrew Cask installed and everything was fine. Then I uninstalled Homebrew Cask like so:

```
$ brew untap caskroom/versions
$ brew uninstall brew-cask
```

Here are the current taps:

```
$ brew tap
homebrew/versions
```

Yet I see stuff from Cask when searching for items that wouldn't be part of Homebrew itself (like Graphical programs, aText, Fantastical etc.):

```
$ brew search atext
Caskroom/cask/atext
```

Though it doesn't install (as expected):

```
$ brew install atext 
Error: No available formula for atext
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...
Caskroom/cask/atext
```

So the question is why does brew search Caskroom/cask and how do I get rid of it (I don't want Homebrew telling me it has aText, for example, when it can't install it)?

I am running Mac OS X Yosemite.

Comment: use the uninstall homebrew on githib https://gist.github.com/mxcl/1173223

Comment: there is another uninstall link here when i searched for osx yosemite http://www.curvve.com/blog/guides/2013/uninstall-homebrew-mac-osx/

Comment: I want to uninstall Homebrew Cask, not Homebrew itself.

Comment: Someone mentioned in the #homebrew-cask channel that this was a feature. Apparently the Homebew and Homebrew Cask teams are working on better integration. Here's the link I was pointed to in the channel: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/34496

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As of Homebrew version 0.9.5, it appears that `brew search` will find items in `Caskroom/cask/` without actually having Homebrew Cask installed. You can also install them, but this will actually install `brew-cask` as a dependency along the way.

Try:

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/atext
```

Answer (score 147):

For the current version of Brew:

```
$ brew uninstall --cask yed
```

For older versions of Brew:

```
$ brew cask uninstall yed
```

the result:

```
==> Removing App symlink: '/Users/user/Applications/yEd.app'
```

Comment: I almost passed over this answer until I realised it had an extra parameter `brew CASK uninstall <name>`. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Command the terminal to "untap" at the prompt [MacOS Catalina 10.15.2]

**Run**

```
brew untap homebrew/cask-fonts
```

**Expected output**

```
Untapping homebrew/cask-fonts...
Untapped 1571 casks (1,713 files, 11.4MB)
```